# how can I change the default owner of the public schema on postgresql database?

Tags: database, postgresql, schema, database-schema

When I create a database with my user the public schema is created with "postgres" user. I can create and drop tables in this schema but I can't drop the schema or change the owner.

I'm installing Phinx migrations for a php project. This is a mature project which has many tables. For the first migration on the up() method I load a sql file with the schema of the database and on the down() method I would drop schema (tables, triggers, procedures...)

```
class FirstMigration extends AbstractMigration
{
    public function up()
    {
        $schema= file_get_contents('./database/migrations/schemaDB.sql');
        $this->execute($schema);
    }

    public function down()
    {
        $this->execute("DROP SCHEMA public CASCADE");
        $this->execute("CREATE SCHEMA public");
    }
}
```

When I do rollback, I have an error:

> Insufficient privilege: 7 ERROR: You must be owner of public schema.

[image]

When I create the database I choose the user "citest"

[image]

But the owner by default for the public schema is "postgres"!

[image]

and I can't change it.

My user is the owner of database but isn't the owner of the public schema which is the user "postgres".

Comment: You could change the owner once by running `alter schema public owner to ...` as the `postgres` user

Comment: I try it but I can't because I'm not owner of the schema. I try it with Navicat UI and with the sentence.

Comment: As I said: you must connect as `postgres` (the superuser) and then run that statement once.

Comment: I haven't permissions with `postgres`  user but a found a solution. I executed `DROP OWNED BY CURRENT_USER CASCADE`instead `DROP SCHEMA`.

Answer (score 2):

The default user of the `public` schema is set by the template database (called `template1`) that Postgres copies when it creates a new DB. If you want to change defaults of newly created databases you need to modify `template1`. For example you can `DROP SCHEMA public` from `template1`. Now you won't need to start your migrations by dropping `public` because it won't exist. Of course to do this you'll need to (at least temporarily) login with a user that has permissions to edit `template1`.

For more information read this thread on the Postgres mailing list, https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAFjNrYu8GqD%3D17DimG9QtWoV1hPviqHxaZp2umWAPkpUOFAGYg%40mail.gmail.com.